# Hbase indexing using solr

Tags: solr, hbase, lucidworks

I am trying to index hbase table using solr. I have followed the steps given on the following link
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Hbase-indexing-to-Solr-with-HDP-Search/ta-p/244387

But the numDocs in Solr admin remains 0.
My Hbase version is 1.1.2 and solR version is 6.6.2.
Do you have any solution?

Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK you are creating hbase table and populating collection. dynamically isnt it ? if so make sure that WAL is enabled for hbase table while populating the data in hbase table

Comment: Yes, @RamGhadiyaram . The WAL is enabled.